# How to set height and width and align button programatically?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button, android-layoutparams

I have to get the date picker dialog and time picker dialog in one dialog. For this I have a code in this the buttons are added to set the time and date and to switch between date and time picker dialog.

I have set a drawable resourse to the buttons , it looks very bigger. I want to make the buttons small to look good in the dialog.

I tried to arrange it's width and height but I am unable to get perfect size. It looks like below :

[image]

code:

```
 public class CustomDateTimePicker implements View.OnClickListener {
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

    private final int SET_DATE = 100, SET_TIME = 101, SET = 102, CANCEL = 103;

    private Button btn_setDate, btn_setTime, btn_set, btn_cancel;

    private Calendar calendar_date = null;

    private Activity activity;

    private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

    private Dialog dialog;

    private boolean is24HourView = true, isAutoDismiss = true;

    private int selectedHour, selectedMinute;

    public CustomDateTimePicker(Activity a,
                                ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) {
        activity = a;
        iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

        dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                resetData();
            }
        });

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        View dialogView = getDateTimePickerLayout();
        dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
    }

    public View getDateTimePickerLayout() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_match_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_wrap_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frame_match_wrap = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);

        LinearLayout linear_main = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_main.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
        linear_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linear_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LinearLayout linear_child = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_child.setLayoutParams(linear_wrap_wrap);
        linear_child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout linear_top = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_top.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

        btn_setDate = new Button(activity);
        btn_setDate.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_setDate.setText("Set Date");
        btn_setDate.setId(SET_DATE);
        btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_setDate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.signup);


        btn_setTime = new Button(activity);
        btn_setTime.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_setTime.setText("Set Time");
        btn_setTime.setId(SET_TIME);
        btn_setTime.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_setTime.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.signup);

        linear_top.addView(btn_setDate);
        linear_top.addView(btn_setTime);

        viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(activity);
        viewSwitcher.setLayoutParams(frame_match_wrap);

        datePicker = new DatePicker(activity);
        timePicker = new TimePicker(activity);
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                selectedHour = hourOfDay;
                selectedMinute = minute;
            }
        });

        viewSwitcher.addView(timePicker);
        viewSwitcher.addView(datePicker);

        LinearLayout linear_bottom = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_match_wrap.topMargin = 8;
        linear_bottom.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

        btn_set = new Button(activity);
        btn_set.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_set.setText("Set");
        btn_set.setId(SET);
        btn_set.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_set.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_shape);

        btn_cancel = new Button(activity);
        btn_cancel.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_cancel.setText("Cancel");
        btn_cancel.setId(CANCEL);
        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_cancel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_background);

        linear_bottom.addView(btn_set);
        linear_bottom.addView(btn_cancel);

        linear_child.addView(linear_top);
        linear_child.addView(viewSwitcher);
        linear_child.addView(linear_bottom);

        linear_main.addView(linear_child);

        return linear_main;
    }
 }
```

I want to make these buttons small and some space around them. Please help. Thank you..

Comment: Why don't you just create an xml layout? You can do this in a much more optimized way.

Comment: how can I create xml layout? and use in this class?@McAwesomville

Comment: You've been doing everything programmatically. You should just create your own Custom Dialog, it's so much simpler. Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13341560/4625829). It's a start. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  btn.height = 60;
  btn.width = 60;
  btn_set.setLayoutParams(btn);
```

You can also add rules and set margins for Button by setting relative layout params like

```
  btn.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
  btn.leftMargin = 220;
```

I hope you solve your problem very soon...!!:):)

Comment: button parameters in this are set like: 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f); @bhumika rijiya